# Asp.net MVC - Save Photos And Use Them in Three Mvc Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, directory

I'm using Asp.net Mvc C# for building websites - frontend and admin(backoffice) application.

First, I created a project X.FrontendApp and I used MVC "**Areas**" for backoffice. But I want to seperate them as two projects because this admin will be common for two frontend applications. So now projects looks like this; X.FrontendAppA, X.FrontendAppB and X.Admin

My question is; I used Upload folder in X.FrontendApp like;
"**~/Upload/GalleryPhotos/**"

If I will use this folder structure, I'll save photos under admin application, under the upload folder. And I can't reach this folder from my X.FrontendAppA and X.FrontendAppB. So what are my options to solve this problem?

- I can use AWS/Azure blob storage to save photos.
- I can use Cloudflare etc. for photos.
- I could save photos in DB as binary. But I have limited DB size.
  So those two options need costs / extra money.

What can I do to fix this problem?

( Note: I'm using shared hosting. But I deployed admin & frontend application without an error like; abc.com admin.abc.com They are working well but photos are not. )

Comment: If you really don't want/have the option to store them in any other way, you can always create an asp.net API call that enables any other allowed application to get the image you stored in the UploadFolder and return it to wherever it's being requested.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mklink command to create a symbolic link between your Projects